# Kafka to MongoDB using Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm working on a project where i have to process data coming from Kafka cluter, processing it and send it to MongoDB. The application should be deployable on the Pivotal Cloud foundary. After doing some research on the internet, i found the toolkit Spring-Cloud-Dataflow to be interesting since it can be deployed in PCF. I'm wondering how we can use it to create our real time streaming pipeline. For the moment, i'm thinking about using Kafka Streams and Spring Cloud Stream to process and transform the streams of topics but i don't know how to integrate it in SCDF and also how we can send those streams to MongoDB. I'm sorry if my question is not clear, i'm entierly new to those frameworks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mongo develops their own Kafka Connector. Why not use it? It can also be deployed to PCF and requires almost no code

Comment: Thank you for your response. As i have stated, there is some processing and transformation to be made before writing to MongoDB :)

Comment: That can be accompilshed with Kafka Streams API in Spring-Kafka / Cloud Streams. Read from Kafka, write back to a separate topic, then pull processed topic data out into Mongo

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [named-destination](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/named-destinations/) support in SCDF to directly consume events from Kafka or any other Spring Cloud Stream supported [message broker implementations](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#binder-implementations).

Now, for the write portion, you can use the out-of-the-box [MongoDB-sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/mongodb/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-mongodb) application that we build, maintain, and ship.

If you have to do some processing before you write to MongoDB, you can create a custom Spring Cloud Stream application with the desired binder implementation [see: [dev-guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/)/[docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_quick_start)].

To put this all together, if we assume you have events coming from a Kafka topic named `Customers`, and the custom processor doing some transformation on each of the received payloads (let's assume the name of the processor as `CustomerTransformer`), and finally the writing part to MongoDB.

Here's a take of this streaming data pipeline use-case designed from SCDF's Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still have some question about your solution.
1- What's the difference between using the out-of-the-box MongoDB-sink application and the one which is already built in SCDF ?
2- The stream must be deployable into a Pivotal Cloud Foundary . Is there any change to be made for our application ?
3- Can the custom processor like **CustomerTransformer** take two topics as source and do a join `between them using kafka streams built with Spring Cloud Stream ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 1) Apps are registred in SCDF. MongoDB sink is an app that we build, and it can be used as-is in a Stream. There is no other difference. 2) No special treatment required for PCF or K8s — app works exactly the same. 3) Please read Spring Cloud Stream docs, and yes, multiple inputs and output channels are possible. Also possible with Kafka Streams. See [Spring Cloud Stream samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. There is so much to do with SCS, i'll read the docs :)

Comment: I begin learning about SCDF and found out there is a lot of versions:Hoxton,Greenwich,Finchley,Edgware,Dalston. Which one would you recommend ?

Comment: You may want to choose the latest GA version of Spring Cloud Stream. The version matrix is listed on the [website](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#release-trains).

Comment: I have chosen the Greenwich since it's the one used in links dev-guide/docs you joined and it's working well :D